# nodemon app crashed - and returning error that ERR MODULE NOT FOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, localhost, node-modules

i am trying to run the nodemon server for the openAI GPT

here is the .json file

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "openai": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

this is the server.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

dotenv.config();
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const app = express();
app.use((cors()));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        message: 'Hello form Codex',
    })
});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const prompt = req.body.prompt; //front end

        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `${prompt}`,
            temperature: 0,
            max_tokens: 3000,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0.5,
            presence_penalty: 0,
        });
        res.status(200).send({
            bot: response.data.choices[0].text
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({ error })
    }
})

app.listen(5000, ()=> console.log('Server is running on port http://localhost:5000'));
```

here is my code kindly solve it that which my server is returning the error in the terminal

```
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

i am trying to run the server on the terminal with the command = npm run server

but it thorow the error ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND and [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

i am expecting to run the server and it do not return any error

Comment: You're using express but it is not in your dependencies, are you sure you have installed it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed express NPM Package

Run

`npm i express`

In your terminal in project root  directory